# Error al mostrar los datos recibidos de PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery, ajax

Hago una consulta a la base de datos `MySQL`, los datos de esta consulta los introduzco en un array que devuelvo al cliente. El array se recibe bien pero a la hora de recorrerlo en el cliente para mostrar los datos, no se hace de forma correcta y no sé que puede estar pasando.

Esta es la petición `AJAX` que realizo para recibir los datos del servidor

```
        $.ajax({
        url: './get_carta.php',
        type: 'get',
        data: {categoria: categoria},
        datatype: 'json',

        success: (platosCategoria) => {
            for(let i = 0; i < platosCategoria.length; i++){
                console.log(platosCategoria);
                platoHTML+=
                '<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">'
                    '<div class="offer-item">'
                        '<img src="images/'+platosCategoria[i].IMAGEN+'" alt="" class="img-responsive">'+
                        '<div>'+
                            '<!--<h3>PLATO 1</h3>-->'+
                            '<p>'+platosCategoria[i].PLATO+'</p>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<span class="offer-price">'+platosCategoria[i].PRECIO+'</span>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>';
            }
            $('#platos-categoria').html(platoHTML);
        }
    })
```

Y este es el script PHP

```
    $query = "SELECT 
            cc.CATEGORIA, 
            c.ID_PLATO, c.PLATO, c.PRECIO, c.IMAGEN
        FROM
            carta c
        INNER JOIN 
            categoria_carta cc ON c.ID_CATEGORIA = cc.ID_CATEGORIA
        WHERE
            cc.CATEGORIA = '$_GET[categoria]'";

$result = $conn->query($query);


while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $platosCategoria[] = $fila;
};

if(!empty($platosCategoria)){
    echo json_encode($platosCategoria);
}else{
    echo "Platos no disponibles";
}
```

[image: Esta es la respuesta del servidor tras realizar la consulta]

[image: Y esto es lo que muestra la consola de Chrome cuando recibo los datos del cliente]

Veo que el bucle `for` se recorre 478 veces, que imagino que son los caracteres que componen el array. He hecho esto muchas veces, con scripts muy parecidos pero no sé por qué en esta ocasión está ocurriendo esto.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Estás haciendo un `platosCategoria.length` .. de cuanto es ese lenght total ?

Comment: Posiblemente los 478 caracteres que forman el array sea el length. Pero siempre lo he hecho así y me funcionaba bien. No entiendo por qué en este caso no. Quizás sea un error pequeño que no estoy viendo pero no sé por qué no lo muestra correctamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podría ser porque estás recibiendo el dato en tipo **string**, deberías intentar usar [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), el cual te convertirá el string a un objeto (siempre y cuando tenga una estructura JSON válida)

```js
$.ajax({
    url: './get_carta.php',
    type: 'get',
    data: {
        categoria: categoria
    },
    datatype: 'json',

    success: function(platosCategoria) {
        platosCategoria = JSON.parse(platosCategoria);
        let platoHTML = '';
        for (let i = 0; i < platosCategoria.length; i++) {
            console.log(platosCategoria);
            platoHTML += `<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
            <div class="offer-item">
            <img src="images/${platosCategoria[i].IMAGEN}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                <div>
                <!--<h3>PLATO 1</h3>-->
                <p>${platosCategoria[i].PLATO}</p>
                </div>
                <span class="offer-price"> ${platosCategoria[i].PRECIO}</span>
                </div>
                </div>`;
        }
        $('#platos-categoria').html(platoHTML);
    }
});
```

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta, es que tienes errores de sintaxis con las comillas simples, para tener strings de varias líneas, usa [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Además, estás sobrescribiendo una variable no definida (`platoHTML`), haciendo que se pueda usar de manera GLOBAL, puedes usar [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) para definir la variable localmente y que no se salga del scope de la función

Comment: Era la solución. Aún así, en el HTML se muestran 8 elementos en lugar de 4. Gracias por la ayuda. Saludos